# Tbody vertical scrollbar WITHOUT fix width

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, html-table

Exactly like the title says. There are hundreds of posts around with this question and all answers are forcing me to use fix width, but that's not the real world.

I want my `td` to use `%` and still have `tbody` scrollable.

I want what Isaac Betesh asked in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283492/how-to-apply-vertical-scrollbar-for-tbody#comment24724651_13283791) on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13283791) to this question "[How to apply vertical scrollbar for TBODY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283492/how-to-apply-vertical-scrollbar-for-tbody)":

> This example has exact pixel width for each td and th. Is there a way to use % widths instead of px and accomplish the same?

Edit:
Don't want to include dozens of examples, because they're all over Stack Overflow, but this is the classic one: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/2/).

If you just change the content in `thead` like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/2168/), it all gets out of sync between `thead` and `tbody`.

The solution

```
 display:block;
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Please update and include some code and a jsFiddle if possible :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scrollbar that added to tbody is the problem,I set thead width to `width: calc(100% - 17px)` and some other css and problem solved,
this is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shirin_Abdolahi/rBkRS/6/)
and this is what I've added to your css :

```
thead, tbody, tr, td { display: block}
thead {
        width: calc(100% - 17px);
}
tbody td, thead td {
    width: 40%;
    display:inline-block
}
table {
    background-color: #aaa;
    width:50%
}
```

Comment: My example was a lot more complexe, but the calc(100% - 17px); did the trick. Thanks

Comment: 17 px? What if the user change the width of the scroll bar? Or uses a different OS? Isn't it ridiculous that an obvious task with tables (freeze the first row) hasn't yet been implemented after 20+ years of HTML?