# How to make a part of table scrollable?

Tags: php, html, css

I am newbie in php and basic html.I am searching for a solution in my project.I have a table and I want to scroll only a part of table. That is avoid first row,first column and last row and other part of table to be scrollable.Table is dynamically created, and its width is maximum 1000px. if the width is more than 1000px, I want to scroll only a part of table.Is it possible?

Comment: by first `row`, did you mean `thead`?

Comment: I mean fix the first column and other are scrollable

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no ready solution exists - probably.

There are solutions on how to scroll tbody independant of thead. You can search, there were even some answers here on stackoverflow - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283492/how-to-apply-vertical-scrollbar-for-tbody) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345390/tabletbody-scrollable).

But, in your case you also need a fixed bottom.

```
<table>
<thead>
     <!-- fixed part -->
</thead>
<tbody>
     <!-- scroll that part -->
</tbody>
<tbody>
     <!-- fixed part -->
</tbody>
```

So, I suggest you find the solution and apply it to a particular tbody. That should work.

Also, [here](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html) is one of the working examples.